# Android List How to view items go to extra details page when clicked w/ database

Tags: android, android-intent

I making an app where I have different activities in my database, which displays on the custom list view I have made, which shows the user basic activity info. I have added an onItemClickListener to the list view so it takes the user to a 'details' page where I want to display more information from the database. The intent works to send the user to the new activity and I have also used the putExtra function in my intent to send the position of the list view click and have that position coming up in a toast on the new page to test it was working. Everything is fine but now I am trying to get the information from the database. I have tried looking at many different tutorials but nothing is working, I am thinking that if I can get the title of the activity to send across in the putExtra, then I will just be able to display stuff from activity table where the putExtra title info = title in the table. But I can't seem to get the title from the table and put it in the putExtra function. I am working with Sugar ORM database.

Here is where I display the list view on the ViewData class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_data);
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.viewAll_listview);
    long count = Activitytable.count(Activitytable.class);
    if(count>0) {
        Activitytable.listAll(Activitytable.class);
        final List<Activitytable> activitytable = Activitytable.listAll(Activitytable.class);
        ViewAllListView madapter = new ViewAllListView(getApplicationContext(), activitytable);
        listView.setAdapter(madapter);
        listView.setClickable(true);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                Object o = getItem(position);
                Activitytable AT = Activitytable.findById(Activitytable.class,activitytable.get(position).getId());
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Details.class);
                i.putExtra("listPosition",position);
                startActivity(i);

            }
            public Object getItem(int position) {return position;}
        });

    }
        else

            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data Available in Table", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
```

Here is my custom list view class ViewAllListView:

```
public class ViewAllListView extends BaseAdapter {

public Context tcontext;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public ViewHolder holder=null;
private List<Activitytable> activitytable = new ArrayList<>();

ViewAllListView(Context context, List<Activitytable> values)
{
    this.tcontext = context;
    this.activitytable = values;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


public int getCount(){
    return activitytable.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {return position;}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {return 0;}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_for_listview_show,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_textview);
        holder.Overall_rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.overallrating_textview);
        holder.Category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_textview);
        holder.Average_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.averageprice_textview);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.title.setText(this.activitytable.get(position).Title);
    holder.Overall_rating.setText(this.activitytable.get(position).Overall_rating);
    holder.Category.setText(this.activitytable.get(position).Category);
    holder.Average_price.setText(this.activitytable.get(position).Average_price);
    return convertView;
}
static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView title, Overall_rating, Category, Average_price;
}
}
```

And here is what I have so far on my Details class:

```
public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView titletext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    titletext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletext);

    String data = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("listPosition").toString();

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),String.valueOf(data),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider these changes:

**ViewAllListView.java** (You need to return the item to be able to access it)

```
 public class ViewAllListView extends BaseAdapter {

  .....

  public Object getItem(int position) {
     //instead of return position;
     return activitytable.get(position); 
  }

  .....
}
```

**ViewData.java** (You can retrieve the item, cast it into an Activitytable object) and get the name)

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

       ......
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            Activitytable o = (Activitytable) getItem(position);
            //you can retrieve the name from object o 
            i.putExtra("listName", o.getName());

       ......
 }
```

Let me know if it helps! Happy programming!

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to help me with displaying the name of the activity  (title) once I am on the details page because it displays in the Toast perfectly, but will not display in the textview I have. I am trying to very simply use the same type of thing that I used in the toast: titletext.setText(String.valueOf(data));

Comment: It keeps having errors when I test and click onto the details page on the phone. The error is unable to start activity... 'java.lang.nullPointerException: attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence) on a null object reference'

Comment: @KatyJones sure, but it seem to be a total different question from this. Perhaps you can start a question, and link me there or find a similar answer if it had already been answered before.